# Calling user-defined function on jQuery object

Tags: javascript, jquery, colors

I want the color of the text to change when I click it. This is the code I'm using right now:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#colorChanger p").click(function() {
        $(this).changeColor();
    });

    function changeColor() {
        $(this).css("color", "white");
    };
})
```

I also have this code [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xME2L/2/). What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Post your code here, not just on another site.

Comment: alright, will do that next time. it was my first time so woops :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xME2L/5/

If you wish to add a function so you can call it on whatever is returned from $(), you must use:

```
$.fn.functionName = function() {}
```

Comment: I think this was good to know for future references too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is [my solution](http://jsfiddle.net/xME2L/7/). You were not passing the object correctly to the changeColor function. I would also recommend declaring changeColor outside of the document.ready function.

Comment: Hmm... that's a different way to do it. Thanks!

Comment: I agree with this, as it keeps things separate. Generally you want to define your functions this way, or if you're concerned about naming conflicts: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/474590/

Answer (score 0):

The changecolor function was never assigned to the jquery el object.

An alternative to [agmcleod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382574/calling-user-defined-function-on-jquery-object/7382586#7382586)'s solution would be :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#colorChanger p").click(function(){
           changeColor($(this));
         });

        function changeColor(el){
            el.css("color","white");
        };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dq6yv/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [agmcleod's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382574/x/7382586#7382586), you could call `changeColor` this way (without changing `changeColor`):

```
changeColor.call(this);
```

**Demo the change [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xME2L/9/).**

Answer (score 0):

You should define changeColor as a JQuery plugin if you want to call it like $(this).changeColor(); :

```
$(document).ready(function(){            
    $("#colorChanger p").click(function(){
        $(this).changeColor();
    });

    $.fn.changeColor = function() {
      this.css("color","white");
    };
```

})